# Understanding the basics of second quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators

I am new to quantum field theory and I am trying to understand how to work with quantum field operators and the notations that are used here.
Context:
Assume a hamiltonian with operator: $\hat{W} = t\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}(\hat{b}^\dagger + \hat{b})$ , where $t$ is a constant, $\hat{b}^\dagger$ and $\hat{b}$ correspond to the creation and annilhation operators for bosons respectfully. $\hat{a}^\dagger$ and $\hat{a}$ are the creation and annihilation operators for fermions. I am given that the ground state is $a^\dagger\left|0\right>$, thus ground state contains 1 fermion. These are the questions that I have:

1. How would a state look if I had N bosons and M fermions, $\left|T_{N,M}\right>$, in it? How do I write this notation?
2. How do I calculate the matrix elements for $\langle g|W|g \rangle$? I know that this is supposed to be zero, I found that out by the following calculation:
   $\langle g|\hat{W}|g\rangle = t\langle g|\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a}\hat{b}^\dagger|g \rangle = tc \langle g|\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a}|1,1 \rangle = tc\langle g|1,1\rangle = 0$.
   Where $\left|1,1\right>$ is a state with 1 boson and 1 fermion. I do not know if I did this correctly or not.
3. And how do I work this out for $\langle g|W|T_{N,M} \rangle$.

Comment: Why do you want to discuss a very specific, quite complicated, example without understanding the basics first?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding second quantization and using it on operators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/806409/) Please don't ask the very same question again if the previous post was closed. Instead, edit the post accordingly and try to re-open.

Comment: Previously my question was closed due to not be specific with its question, I fixed that however the question is still down. I know that this is quite a complicated question to ask, however I still need help understanding the basics, thats all im asking. I dont understand this question, and flagging it is not helping